# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on ABAddressBookSave(...) iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I am having a problem where my app crashes trying to save an Address Book. The crash is due to an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and occurs during `ABCDBContextSaveMultiValue` because of a call to `CFArrayGetCount(...)`

Therefore I figure I have isolated the problem but have no idea how to fix it. Here's my code:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

for (int i=0; i<[pledgeInfo count]; i++ ) {
    NSArray * pledgeObj = [pledgeInfo objectAtIndex:i];
    ABRecordRef personRef = ABPersonCreate();
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    if( !ABRecordSetValue(personRef, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, [pledgeObj objectAtIndex:1], &error) ) {/*ErrorHandle*/}
    if( !ABRecordSetValue(personRef, kABPersonLastNameProperty, [pledgeObj objectAtIndex:2], &error) ) {/*ErrorHandle*/}
    if( !ABRecordSetValue(personRef, kABPersonEmailProperty, [pledgeObj objectAtIndex:4], &error) ) {/*ErrorHandle*/}

    // ERROR IS IN HERE SOMEWHERE
    ABMutableMultiValueRef phNums = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
    ABMultiValueIdentifier abi;
    if( !ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phNums, [pledgeObj objectAtIndex:3], kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, &abi) ) {/*ErrorHandle*/}
    if( !ABRecordSetValue(personRef, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phNums, &error) ) {/*ErrorHandle*/}
    if( !ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, personRef, &error) ) {/*ErrorHandle*/}
}
    NSLog(@"%@",addressBook);
    CFErrorRef cferr = NULL;
    if( !ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &cferr) ) {/*ErrorHandle*/
}
```

Comment: The NSLog also shows that the addressBook is **not** null.

Comment: **PROBLEM SOLVED** E-Mail has to be a multivalue just like phone numbers.

Comment: @user367817 You can post your answer as well(Code snippet). So that it will help others too.